# creating a dictionary from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got an array of objects of the following form:

```
let postArray = [
   {
      id = 1,
      body = "some text"
   },
   {
      id = 2,
      body = "some other text"
   }
]
```

which I want to rearange to the following form:

```
{
    posts: {
      1: {
          id = 1,
          body = "some text"
       },
      2: {
          id = 2,
          body = "some other text"
       }
    }
}
```

How can I do that using ES6?

Comment: These syntax are totally wrong. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: What is the goal of doing `n: { id = n, ...`?

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research. [Search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO. Attempt to do the work. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce your array:

```
let postArray = [
   {
      id: 1,
      body: "some text"
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      body: "some other text"
   }
]
const posts = postArray.reduce((acc, b) => ({...acc, [b.id]: b}), {})
const result = { posts }
```